# Android Studio 3.1 read SQL Table from Emulator

Tags: android, sqlite

For debugging I would like to pull a SQL Table from my Emulator. In the new AS 3.1 there is no Device Explorer - how can I do that now?
Thank you

Comment: Found the answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trswX8x-dnI

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQlLite , it is embedded in all Android Systems.